# how to write a small, complete example of an Annotation Processor with maven?

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation

I need to implement an Annotation Processor that generates a Java class related to the annotated class. However, my biggest challenge at the moment is understanding how to use Maven to implement such an Annotation Processor and make it work.

Annotation is like:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Tag {
    String value() default "";
}
```

processor is like:

```java
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"Tag"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_11)
public class TagProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        for (TypeElement annotation : annotations) {
            var annotatedElements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
            for (var element : annotatedElements) {
                if (element.getKind() == ElementKind.CLASS) {
                    var className = ((TypeElement) element).getQualifiedName().toString();
                    var packageName = className.substring(0, className.lastIndexOf('.'));
                    var simpleClassName = className.substring(className.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                    var infoClassName = simpleClassName + "Info";
                    var tagValue = element.getAnnotation(Tag.class).value();

                    // Generate the source code for the new class
                    var infoClassSource = generateInfoClass(packageName, infoClassName, tagValue);

                    // Write the generated source code to a new file
                    try {
                        writeSourceFile(packageName, infoClassName, infoClassSource);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR,
                                "Error generating " + infoClassName + ": " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private String generateInfoClass(String packageName, String infoClassName, String tagValue) {
        return "package " + packageName + ";\n\n" +
                "public class " + infoClassName + " {\n" +
                "    private String tag = \"" + tagValue + "\";\n\n" +
                "    public String getTag() {\n" +
                "        return tag;\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";
    }

    private void writeSourceFile(String packageName, String className, String source) throws IOException {
        var filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
        var fileObject = filer.createSourceFile(packageName + "." + className);
        try (var writer = fileObject.openWriter()) {
            writer.write(source);
        }
    }
}
```